# Displaying a message on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I'm using Google maps in my academic project,from few weeks onwards a message in displaying on map whenever I do certain operations on map like zoom-in,zoom-out.What might be the reason?Is I need configure any thing in my code.[image]

You can see that message in above image,message is titled by 'Map Data'.We are using open layers maps in our project and coding language is PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read here that one cause might be some element covering up the map data copyright, but I found some complaints of the same notice popping up without mentioning this.

The most promising option I found is [a page saying the solution is to upgrade to 2.12](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Release/2.11/GoogleMaps37) or if you cannot, then apply a patch after including the OpenLayers.js

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="../lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
    OpenLayers.Layer.Google.v3.repositionMapElements = function() {
        // This is the first time any Google layer in this mapObject has been
        // made visible.  The mapObject needs to know the container size.
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.mapObject, "resize");

        var div = this.mapObject.getDiv().firstChild;
        if (!div || div.childNodes.length < 3) {
            this.repositionTimer = window.setTimeout(
                OpenLayers.Function.bind(this.repositionMapElements, this),
                250
            );
            return false;
        }

        var cache = OpenLayers.Layer.Google.cache[this.map.id];
        var container = this.map.viewPortDiv;

        // move the ToS and branding stuff up to the container div
        // depends on value of zIndex, which is not robust
        for (var i=div.children.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
            if (div.children[i].style.zIndex == 1000001) {
                var termsOfUse = div.children[i];
                container.appendChild(termsOfUse);
                termsOfUse.style.zIndex = "1100";
                termsOfUse.style.bottom = "";
                termsOfUse.className = "olLayerGoogleCopyright olLayerGoogleV3";
                termsOfUse.style.display = "";
                cache.termsOfUse = termsOfUse;
            }
            if (div.children[i].style.zIndex == 1000000) {
                var poweredBy = div.children[i];
                container.appendChild(poweredBy);
                poweredBy.style.zIndex = "1100";
                poweredBy.style.bottom = "";
                poweredBy.className = "olLayerGooglePoweredBy olLayerGoogleV3 gmnoprint";
                poweredBy.style.display = "";
                cache.poweredBy = poweredBy;
            }
            if (div.children[i].style.zIndex == 10000002) {
                container.appendChild(div.children[i]);
            }
        }

        this.setGMapVisibility(this.visibility);
    };
    </script>
    <script src="google-v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this issue was solved in the latest versions of OpenLayers.